# compile error variable not defined VBA

Tags: vba, excel, variables, ms-word

I've created a macro to move information from Excel into existing tables in a Word document. When I try to compile, I'm getting a "Compile error: variable not defined" error on `wdCollapseStart` within the statement `Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart`. I simplified to `Selection.Collapse`, but then I got the same error on the next line with `wdRow`. `wdCollapse` and `wdRow` are not variables, so I don't understand why I'm getting this error, especially when the exact same statement functions perfectly if I run it through the immediate window from Word. To clarify, I've written this macro for Excel, but the macro has to manipulate a Word document as well.

Full code below (the offending statement is in the first `with` statement):

```
Option Explicit
Dim Word_App As Object
Dim Word_Doc As Object

Sub IDA_Creator()

Dim Starting_Sheet As Integer: Starting_Sheet = 4
Dim Ending_Sheet As Integer: Ending_Sheet = Worksheets.Count - 1

'Activates first category worksheet
Worksheets(Starting_Sheet).Activate

'Get the name of the destination Word file
Dim IDA_Word As String
IDA_Word = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Word Files (*.DOCX), *.DOCX", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

'Open Word
Set Word_App = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Word_App.Visible = True
Set Word_Doc = Word_App.Documents.Open(IDA_Word)

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 3

    Call TrimTable

    Call Move_To_Table(Starting_Sheet, i)

    Dim j As Integer

    For j = Starting_Sheet To Ending_Sheet

        Call Copy_To_Word(i)

        'Prepares Word table for next Category (unless it's the last category
        If ActiveSheet.Index > Worksheets.Count - 1 Then

            ActiveSheet.Next.Select

            With Word_Doc

                Selection.InsertRowsBelow (2)
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
                Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdRow, Extend:=wdExtend
                Selection.Cells.Merge
                Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

            End With

        End If

    Next j

    Worksheets(Starting_Sheet).Activate

Next i

'Save Word Document and Close Word
With Word_Doc

    .Save

End With

Word_App.Quit
Set Word_Doc = Nothing
Set Word_App = Nothing

End Sub

'Trims the table to the first category and criterion
Function TrimTable()

With Word_Doc

    With Word_App.Selection.Find

        .Text = "Table " & i
        .Style = "Caption"
        .Execute

    End With

    Selection.MoveDown Count:=4
    Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdTable, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Rows.Delete

End With

End Function

'Moves the cursor to the first cell of the next table, formats table with correct style
Function Move_To_Table(Starting_Sheet As Integer, i As Integer)

Sheets(Starting_Sheet).Activate

With Word_Doc

    With Word_App.Selection.Find

        .Text = "Table " & i
        .Style = "Caption"
        .Execute

    End With

    'Ensures first row of table is in "CellHeadingL" style
    Selection.MoveDown
    Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdRow, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Style = "CellHeadingL"
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

    'Clears boilerplate text
    Selection.MoveDown
    Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdTable, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart

End With

End Function

'Copies criteria text from Excel to Word
Function Copy_To_Word(i As Integer)

    'Copies category name from Excel
    Selection.Copy

    'Pastes category name into Word
    With Word_Doc

        Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdRow, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
        Selection.Style = "CellBodyL"
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
        Selection.MoveDown

    End With

    'Determines number of subcategories and criteria
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select
    Dim Number_Criteria As Integer: Number_Criteria = Selection.Rows.Count - 2

    'Adds correct number of rows to Word table, positions cursor at top row
    With Word_Doc

        Selection.InsertRowsBelow (Number_Criteria - 1)
        Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
        Selection.MoveUp

    End With

    'Selects the first subcategory or criterion from Excel and copies to clipboard
    Selection(1).Select
    Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select

    'Begins copying to Word
    For i = 1 To Number_Criteria

        Selection.Copy

        'Checks whether there's a subcategory (merged) cell in Excel, formats Word table to match and pastes subcategory into Word
        If ActiveCell.MergeCells = True Then

            With Word_Doc

                Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdRow, Extend:=wdExtend
                Selection.Cells.Merge
                Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
                Selection.Style = "CellBodyL"
                Selection.Font.Bold = True

            End With

        'Excel cell isn't a subcategory (merged) cell in Excel, paste criterion into Word
        Else

        With Word_Doc

            Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
            Selection.Style = "CellBodyL"

        End With

        End If

        'Moves to next cell
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select

    Next i

    'Puts cursor in position for next pass (Preferred or Optional criteria)
    Selection.Offset(5, 0).Select

End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

*Excel* VBA doesn't know about predefined Word constants such as `wdCollapseStart`. According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923(v=office.11).aspx) `wdCollapseStart` is equal to `1`. One solution is to just directly use the numbers that such constants refer to (using the linked-to documentation). A second solution is to add a reference to `Microsoft Word 14.0 Object Library` (under `Tools/References` in the VBA editor) after which your code should work without modification.

Comment: @PortlandRunner You are correct. I edited the answer to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Turned out, at least partially, to be a missing `End If`. I did add the Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library (there was no option for 14.0), but now I'm getting a similar error:

"Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"

This time, it's on `Selection.MoveDown Count:=4`. I don't get it. Given that I've added Word as an object and that I'm using the `with` statements, this should work, even without the Word Library. But now that I've added the library, it should work and doesn't. Any more ideas?

Comment: I updated the original code so it has the missing `End If`.

Comment: @Vince Earl - "With Word_doc" does not mean that every object within the With block is a member of Word_doc. It's partly a shorthand that lets you say (for example) ".Content" rather than spelling out "Word_doc.Content". To get Word's Selection object you'll probably need to use "Word_app.Selection",which means to use "With" you would use "With Word_App" and then ".Selection"